# Specific object not being affected by any forces when a cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

I have an object that I'm trying to act as a curtain that I have been slowly working on trying to simulate hanging it up onto a frame.

I have simulated it a few times applying the cloth modifier as I hook up each corner to where I want it to go. The problem is now I want to use a little bit of a wind force to push it out a bit, but the problem is the object won't be affected by any force when I've set the cloth modifier on it.

Attached is my .blend file: [image]

On layer 3 is the curtain object (purple deformed plane), and a test grey plane. Both with the cloth modifier set on it. I have added a wind force field too. You can see that only the test grey plane will respond to the forcefield, but not the curtain.

I've tried appending it into a new file but that didn't fix it.

Edit: It may be a problem with the vertices as I joined the curtain object to the test plane object (into one object) and let it play and the test part was still affected but the curtain part not. I did accidentally mess with the weight painting if that might have anything to do with it

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Seems like subdividing a plane too many times can exponentially decrease how little a force will act on it. I had to set the force multiplier of wind on the cloth to about 50 to see a change